# Encrypt a single drive in a system with two drives

Tags: encryption

I am currently trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a machine which has two SSDs where one SSD has a Windows image on it and I want the second one to have an encrypted Ubuntu image on it. The problem is that I only have the option of erasing everything when installing Ubuntu to encrypt it. Is there some way of installing Ubuntu encrypted on one drive without removing the windows drive?

Comment: Have you tried the advanced install?

Answer (score 0):

Power down and disconnect power.
Temporarily physically disconnect the Windows drive data and power cables in the PC
Boot into Ubuntu
Do your encryption
Shut the PC down
Reconnect the Windows drive
reboot.

Comment: It's a laptop so I was hoping to not have to disconnect the windows drive. But I'm starting to think that's the only way.

Comment: @Raf.S When it's asking to erase everything, please stop there, make a screenshot, and exit. Then upload the screenshot to http://imgur.com or some other image file hosting site, Collect the URL of that uploaded file. Click [edit] and paste that link into your question so all may see it. Once we can see where you're at, maybe another way can be found.

Comment: Some newer systems allow you to turn off a drive in UEFI settings, so then it is not seen at all. You then do not have to physically disconnect a drive.